# Server side shows same webpage for client sides

Tags: javascript, streaming, client-side

I made very simple interface that changes a number and plays a sound. With help from here [here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/onclick-increment-number-globally/466197).

I thought alright, simple project finished, but then realized that the computer displaying the page is not the same computer that activates the number increment.

Should I just cast the page, or is it possible to activate the sound and increment on another computer? Meaning that two clients view the same actions on the server?
Casting always look less well, because it’s a video stream, then a crisp webpage just shown on the screen.
Server is Rpi apache.

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week7-bounce.m4a"></audio>


<div class="overlay" id="globalclick">550</div>

html {
    height: 100%;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

body {
    background-image: url("");
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: 300px;
    font-size: 350px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #DA1F37;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 0;
}


    var button = document.getElementById("globalclick"),
        count = 550;
    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
        count += 1;
        button.innerHTML = count;
    });

    function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
    }
```

Code:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beyondallmeadows/wm1fpj7x/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you want any user to be able to update your number and  that all users will then see the same updated number.

If so, it sounds like you want to host the 'number' on a server and when a user clicks the button you send a message to the server to increment the number.

Every user's web page client will then need to update their local display as the number on the server has changed - there are various mechanisms to do this including:

- having your web page/client poll the server every, for example, second and check the latest value of the number.
- using long polling, which is intended to be more efficient. This sends a request to the server and the server does not respond immediately but keeps the connection open so it can respond when it is ready.
- Use WebSockets which allow two way communication with the server.

There are quite a few resources on the web comparing and providing examples of each - for example: https://ably.com/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling

The best approach for you will depend on your particular use case and constraints - it sounds like this may be simply a learning project for you in which case it might be worth experimenting with multiple approaches.